# How to sumproduct(sumifs()) with multiple LIST criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have noticed an interesting quirk with Excel Formulas which I am having a hard time with.

Small Background:

- Dates are in Column A of Data
- Names are in Column B of Data
- Values I am trying to sum up are in Column C of Data

I am trying to sum up all values in C where A matches a set of days and B matches a set of names, both provided in titled LISTS.

To resummarize:

- Criteria #1 is to sum up column C values so long as column A matches a LIST of days
- Criteria #2 is to sum up column C values so long as column B matches a LIST of names

List of Dates is 1 column, called KeyDate
List of Names is 1 column, called KeyNames

The formula I am using is:
`=sumproduct(sumifs(Data!$C:$C, Data!$A:$A, KeyDate[#Data], Data!$B:$B, KeyNames[#Data]))`

What's confusing me is I use a formula like this all the time where I input just one list of stuff (usually dates) using sumproduct(sumifs()). However, the formula clearly breaks down and stops working when I use two lists of stuff. The value I am seeing returned is flat out wrong and it's undercounting by a large amount.

Any advice on how to approach this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Post few sample data and show your desired output.

Comment: `KeyDate[#Data]` and `KeyNames[#Data]` need to be *orthogonal*, i.e. one a *vertical* range, the other *horizontal*. Hence you will need to transpose one of them using the `TRANSPOSE` function within the formula, though note that, if you are not using `O365`, you will need to commit the resulting formula with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

Comment: @JosWoolley Thank you so much!!! This solution has worked. I hugely appreciate it. By any chance, do you know if there is an absolute ceiling to the number of lists you can use? Since one has to be vertical and another must be horizontal, I assume the ceiling is maybe two?

Comment: You're absolutely correct: two is the limit. Beyond that, you need to switch to a `SUMPRODUCT`/`ISNUMBER`/`MATCH` set-up.